# AngularJS - Filter selected property in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, angularjs-filter

Is there any way in angular `$filter('filter')` to filter limited property.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5pzsQ?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="type" ng-model="filter_value" />
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row in data | filter: filter_value">{{row.name +'--'+ row.age}}</li>
      </ul>
    </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [
    {name: "Moroni", age: 50, secret: 'one'},
    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, secret: 'one'},
    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, secret: 'two'},
    {name: "Nephi", age: 29, secret: 'two'},
    {name: "Enos", age: 34, secret: 'two'}
  ];
});
```

**Problem**
I have a property called secret and I do not want the user to filter according to that field i.e., if the user enters `one` or `two`, it should filter according to the proerty `name` and `age` and not `secret`.

Is there a way to do it in built-in angular filter?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a custom filter to manually exclude the undesired fields.

here's a fixed [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4zxzKHul7vgNDWXjSH1f?p=preview)

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="type" ng-model="search.filter_value" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in data | usersListFilter:search.filter_value">{{row.name +'--'+ row.age}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
app.filter('usersListFilter', usersListFilter);

function usersListFilter() {
  return function(usersArray, searchTerm){
    if (!searchTerm) return usersArray;

    var term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    return usersArray.filter(function(user) {
      return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1 || user.age.toString().indexOf(term) != -1;
    });
  };
}
```